# Angular2 disable button

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I know that in **angular2** I can disable a button with the 
**`[disable]`** attribute, for example:

```
<button [disabled]="!isValid" (click)="onConfirm()">Confirm</button>
```

but can I do it using **`[ngClass]`** or **`[ngStyle]`** ? Like so:

```
<button [ngStyle]="{disabled : !isValid}" (click)="onConfirm()">Confirm</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: here is working plnkr for the same http://plnkr.co/edit/MW3vT4XscWcKrDdAwBoE?p=preview

Answer (score 187, accepted):

## **Update**

I'm wondering. Why don't you want to use the `[disabled]` attribute binding provided by Angular 2? It's the correct way to dealt with this situation. I propose you move your `isValid` check via component method.

```
<button [disabled]="! isValid" (click)="onConfirm()">Confirm</button>
```

## The Problem with what you tried explained below

Basically you could use `ngClass` here. But adding class wouldn't restrict event from firing. For firing up event on valid input, you should change `click` event code to below. So that `onConfirm` will get fired only when field is valid.

```
<button [ngClass]="{disabled : !isValid}" (click)="isValid && onConfirm()">Confirm</button>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MW3vT4XscWcKrDdAwBoE?p=preview)

Comment: Well I add that ngClass allready in the button so its looks to me that disabled need to be ther to, why the [disabled] way is preferd?

Comment: @NirSchwartz because it will do both things at a time.. selector css rules will get applied on `button[disabled]` selector based & disabled event will restrict `click` event to fire up on button.. in `ngClass` class thing you need to handle it by own, as I shown in above answer..

Comment: The reason why people want to use [attr.disabled] rather than [disabled] is because angular FormControl's [disabled] cannot be set dynamically. Here is the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271

Comment: You should not be calling a method in a template binding. `[disabled]="!isValid"`

Comment: Ahhaa.. if method has just a variable reference, theb its fine.. If you have complex logic inside a function, then it isn't preferred. You're correct, in this case I can directly call `isValid` flag on UI

Answer (score 41):

I would recommend the following.

```
<button [disabled]="isInvalid()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Isn't it better to avoid function calls in html, as it will be called each tick/cycle?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can

```
<div class="button" [ngClass]="{active: isOn, disabled: isDisabled}"
         (click)="toggle(!isOn)">
         Click me!
 </div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html

Answer (score 7):

If you have a form then the following is also possible:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input name="myfield" type="text" minlenght="3" required ngModel>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xm2dCwqB9p6WygrquUGh?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 5):

Using `ngClass` to disabled the button for invalid form is not good practice in Angular2 when its providing inbuilt features to enable and disable the button if form is valid and invalid respectively without doing any extra efforts/logic.

`[disabled]` will do all thing like if form is valid then it will be enabled and if form is invalid then it will be disabled automatically.

See Example:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="txtName" name="txtname" #textname="ngModel" required>
<input type="button" class="mdl-button" [disabled]="!f.form.valid" (click)="onSave()" name="">
```

Answer (score 4):

May be below code can help:

```
<button [attr.disabled]="!isValid ? true : null">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution since `<button disabled="">` or `<button disabled="false">` is still handled like a disabled button in most browsers

Answer (score 2):

I tried using disabled along with click event. Below is the snippet , the accepted answer also worked perfectly fine , I am adding this answer to give an example how it can be used with disabled and click properties.

```
<button (click)="!planNextDisabled && planNext()" [disabled]="planNextDisabled"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using reactive forms and want to disable some input associated with a form control, you should place this `disabled` logic into you code and call `yourFormControl.disable()` or `yourFormControl.enable()`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest way

```
<!-- Submit Button-->
<button 
  mat-raised-button       
  color="primary"
  [disabled]="!f.valid"
>
  Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <button [disabled]="this.model.IsConnected() == false"
              [ngClass]="setStyles()"
              class="action-button action-button-selected button-send"
              (click)= "this.Send()">
          SEND
        </button>
```

.ts code

```
setStyles() 
{
    let styles = {

    'action-button-disabled': this.model.IsConnected() == false  
  };
  return styles;
}
```