# Reset a input as able again on onClick event after be disable

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

The situation that I have is:
I have a `searchbox` to find colleges, and one of the options that are available in the results is `I can't found my college`. This option let you enter the name of your college manually in other `input type="text"` that only appear if you click on this option. When you click the option to enter the college manually the `searchbox` became disable using and `ng-disable`. The functionality that I need to implement is that when the user click on the disable `searchbox` again this one can be able again, hide the other input text to insert the college manually and let him/her be able to search for college again. This is kind of representation of the situation code:

Template:

```
...    
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input class="searchbox" ng-disabled="!searching" type="text" ng-model="collegeSearch" ng-click="searchingAgain()">
    </div>

    <br>

    <ul class="result-wrapper" ng-show="searching && collegeSearch.length > 0">
      <li>Result 1</li>
      <li>Result 2</li>
      <li ng-click="insertManually()">I can't found my college</li>
    </ul>

    <input ng-show="!searching" type="text" placeholder="Enter the college name manually">
...
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('tAngularApp')
      .controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        this.awesomeThings = [
          'HTML5 Boilerplate',
          'AngularJS',
          'Karma'
        ];

        $scope.searching = true;

        $scope.insertManually = function () {
            $scope.searching = false;
            $scope.collegeSearch = "";
        }

        $scope.searchingAgain = function () {
            console.log('Searching ...');
            $scope.searching = true;
        }

    }]);
```

The problem is that when the searchbox input is disabled the `ng-click` never fire, so i can acivate again the search funcionality.

Can someone help me to find a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Here are some work arounds. [angular using class instead of disabled attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535350/angular2-disable-button). [Event on a disabled input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input). As you state in your question, disabled inputs don't fire events as they would if enabled. Another options is to hide and show a button to search for a custom school. The button could enable and disable the search input instead of clicking the input itself. This is basically using ngClass though (first link).

Comment: Thanks @user3366016 .Could be a possible way, but I need to respect a specific design, so I can't add more elements like buttons.

Comment: From a UI point of view disabling the searchBox does not make sense. It has a valid value that the user choose even if it is called `Can't find my college`

Comment: Well @bhantol as you know, the customer is always right. Besides, is not so crazy the idea, you have 2 ways to pick a college: 1- Searching in the DB options. 2- adding manually your college. If the user picks one way the other should be disabled or hide it. Better for UX.

Comment: Can you use "ng-readonly={{truthy expression}}" instead of "disabled"? As I understand, you'd still be able to use ng-click in a readonly field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-disabled` when true adds attribute `disabled`. Browser is not going to let any pointer events (which generates click event) generate. So the control is not going to receive any clicks or changes.

So you may have to trick this slightly differently:

[Working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/I9Q9LqvmR4s0cA2H0ow9?p=preview)

Please note we added ng-click on the wrapper div `#input-wrapper`. Also `ng-click/ng-change` either one is fine on the input however you may want to use ng-change to not receive unnecessary changes.

```
<div class="input-wrapper" ng-click="searching = true">
  <input class="searchbox" ng-disabled="!searching" type="text" ng-model="collegeSearch" ng-change="searchingAgain()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }">
  <div class="searchbox-reset"></div>
</div>
```