# How to enable and disable a mat-button based on a select form

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This is my mat-button:

```xml
<button class="example-20-width" mat-raised-button disabled>Edit Client</button>
```

How can I control it and make it disabled or not based on whether a select form is emtry or not?

Here is my field form:

```xml
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-select  placeholder="Select customer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of books.data" 
        [value]="food.company">
      {{food.company}}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: `[disabled]="someCondition"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 disable button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535350/angular2-disable-button)

Answer (score 58):

If you look at [Angular Material Demos (button)](https://tina-material-tree.firebaseapp.com/button), which is an older version of Angular Material demo, there is a button performing this.

This demo used to correspond (it's now outdated) to the demo on the Angular GitHub page, see: [github.com - Angular Material - src/demo-app/button](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/button/button-demo.html).

You can simply use:

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="isDisabled">
```

where `isDisabled` is a boolean define in your component.

Comment: This works here, but i the button for material do not show disabled style. When I view source this becomes ng-reflect-disabled, but if i manually change that to just disabled the view updates and angually looks disabled. Any idea how to make it work visually ?

Answer (score 11):

use [disabled] atttribute with button

```
<button class="example-20-width"  [disabled]="true" mat-raised-button disabled>Edit Client</button>
```

Comment: The mat-raised-button by default brings some color to the background that really implies that the button is disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Use [disabled] attribute

ts file

```
review_btn=true;
```

html file

```
  <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="review_btn" color="primary" mat-button (click)="reviewCreate()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use a template reference variable and get the information from the MatSelect:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" #selectedFood>
  <mat-select  placeholder="Select customer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of books.data" 
                 [value]="food.company">
      {{food.company}}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option >
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-stroked-button [disabled]="selectedFood.empty">
  Validate
</button>
```

See [angular official documentation on template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

html file

```
<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" [disabled]="isNextButton" (click)="setSecurity()">Next</button>
```

ts file

```
isNextButton = true;

setSecurity() { this.isNextButton = false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an ngModel to the mat-select, you can then check to see if that model has a value:

```
                <mat-select  placeholder="Select customer" [(ngModel)]="book">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of books.data" 
                      [value]="food.company">
                    {{food.company}}
                  </mat-option>
                  <mat-option >
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
```

You can then check to see if a value has been selected in your button:

```
<button class="example-20-width" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!book">Edit Client</button>
```