# i have used 3 buttons one for week one for month and one for day if click on the week button ,day and month should be disable

Tags: html, angular

i have used 3 buttons one for week one for month and one for day if click on the week button ,day and month should be disable

1D
     
    
      1W
    
    
      1M

while working on one button other two button should be in the disable state

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a good read at how to post questions. Show us the sample code you tried so far. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use property binding and map the boolean flag to disabled attribute of buttons you want to disable.

```
<button [disabled]="flag">Submit</button>
```

See the similar thread for better understanding: [Angular2 disable button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535350/angular2-disable-button)

Answer (score 0):

Refer code below

In app.component.html,

```
<button [disabled]="flagWeek" (click)="disableFun('week')">Week</button>
<button [disabled]="flagMonth" (click)="disableFun('month')">Month</button>
<button [disabled]="flagDay" (click)="disableFun('day')">Day</button>
```

In app.component.ts,

```
flagWeek: boolean;
flagMonth: boolean;
flagDay: boolean;

constructor(){
this.flagWeek = false;
this.flagMonth = false;
this.flagDay = false;
}

disableFun(button: string){
  if(button == "week"){
    this.flagMonth = true;
    this.flagDay = true;
  } else if (button == "month"){
    this.flagWeek = true;
    this.flagDay = true;
  } else {
    this.flagMonth = true;
    this.flagWeek = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir  but if i click week other 2 will disable yes correct but at a time if i  click  month it should enable and other two should disable,how to do sir ...Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are asking something like radio button, correct?